# signup to my website using facebook, but only for specific group member

Tags: php, facebook-authentication

I want to use sign up of facebook into my site, but allow to sign up for my website only for people who joined specific group on facebook. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Ya sure.. get the user level of login user then check the user level of required userlevel for facebook login. 
like this 
Y is log on to the site. We allow to facebook signup for userlevel=6 users. So When Y's user level is 6. So then check

```
if($_SESSION['userlevel']==6){
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
}
```